# DateTime to date conversion, not the correct value

Tags: java, jodatime

I try to convert a string into a datetime:

```
String dateString = "2015-01-14T00:00:00-04:00";
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dt = df.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

If I display `dt.toDate()`

I get: Tue Jan 13 23:00:00 EST 2015

So there is a time problem.

Without the `DateTimeFormatter`, I get the same issue.

Comment: Which timezone are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's getting the correct value - basically 4am UTC, which is midnight in a UTC offset of -04:00 (as per the original text), or 11pm on the previous day for EST (as per the displayed result).

The problem is that you're using `java.util.Date.toString()`, which *always* returns the date in the system time zone. Note that a `java.util.Date` only represents an instant in time - it has no notion of a time zone itself, so its `toString()` method just uses the system default.

If you want to retain the time zone information (or in this case, the offset from UTC information - you don't have a full time zone) then stick to `DateTime` instead of converting to `Date`. Ideally, avoid `java.util.Date`/`java.util.Calendar` entirely. Stick to Joda Time and/or `java.time.*`.

Comment: problem is i need to do some junit test.
i need to compare value from XMLGregorianCalendar to date.
what i done is i'm using a string convert it to a date and affect it to GregorianCalendar, but i get this problem

Comment: @roberttrudel: It's not at all clear where `XMLGregorianCalendar` comes into this at all - why can't you create a `DateTime` to compare the value to? Basically all the code you've shown is working fine - you need to understand that, and update your question with more context.

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar is not shown because the first step i presented don't work.

Comment: @roberttrudel: Again, it *is* working - it's just not doing what you expected. Those are two very different things. First you should understand why the code is giving you the output that it is, accept that that's *correct* behaviour if your machine is in an Eastern time zone, then work out what you need to do for your test.